# Create Edit & Delete Button on DataTables using AJAX ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTables with Ruby On Rails.

have the datasource setup for AJAX but i am trying to add an Edit Button to edit any record individually
I have the following code

```
      $('#table').DataTable({
          ajax: '/get_dataset',
          columns: [
              {data: "id", sortable: false, bVisible: false},
              {title: 'Supplier', data: 'supplier'},
              {title: 'UPC', data: 'upc_fixed'},
              {title: 'Product Code', data: 'product_code'},
              {title: 'Category', data: 'category'},
              {title: 'Description', data: 'description'},
              {title: 'Item Count', data: 'item_count'},
              {title: 'Manage',
                  mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                      return '<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(1) %>'
                  }
              }
          ],
          pageLength: 25
      });
```

What i am having problems with is how to change the `"1"` in this line to be `{data: "id"}`

```
              {title: 'Manage',
                  mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                      return '<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(1) %>'
                  }
              }
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eodk.png)

Comment: Have you tried  return '<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path( #{data: "id"} ) %>' ???

Comment: yes i have doesnt work because "<%=" begins ruby code and  #{data: "id"}  is javascript code